# Color area between two lines based on difference

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've got a chart with two lines, and I want to color the area between them based on which line is above the other one.

This graph shows income and outcome, so if income is more than outcome then the area is green, but if the outcome is more than the income the area turns red.

I can't find a good way to do this in Highcharts. I've tried area charts, but they just color up from zero to the line.

I hope the picture illustration helps, and that someone knows how to do this.

Thanks very much.

My two data sets are just two simple arrays like for instance

```
let income = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 2000, 5000, 9000]
let outcome = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7000, 7000, 7000, 12000]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using [zones](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Carearange%3E.zones) you can change color at given location along the axis you want. This is the syntax:

```
series: {
    name: 'Income',
    data: data,
    zoneAxis: 'x',
    zones: [{value: 1, fillColor: 'green'}, 
            {value: 5, fillColor: 'red}
            ]
}
```

That snippet gives you two zones, green up to 1, and red from 1 to 5. Since it is not very interesting doing this manually, I made an example that does this automatically, see fiddle or bottom of post:

http://jsfiddle.net/zhjyn2o4/1/

In the end you have a `arearange` graph like this:
[image: Example of highcharts graph]

I did this in highstock, but if you prefer using highchart, then it should work using the same code, though it will look a bit different.

You might be tempted to change to `areasplinerange` (which looks better). But using splines it is difficult to find the intersect points, and therefore difficult to color the graph correctly.

```js
let income = [0, 0, 0, 1000, 1000, 2000, 5000, 9000, 12000, 12000, 12000, 5000, 4000, 10000]
let outcome = [0, 0, 7000, 0, 7000, 7000, 7000, 12000, 9000, 9000, 9000, 5000, 5000, 5000]

//create a function to find where lines intersect, to color them correctly
function intersect(x1, x2, y1, y2, y3, y4) {
  return ((x2 * y1 - x1 * y2) - (x2 * y3 - x1 * y4)) / ((y4 - y3) - (y2 - y1));
}

var ranges = []; //stores all the data for the graph like so [x, y1, y2]
var incomeZones = []; //stores the different zones based on where the lines intersect
var incomeBiggerBool = true; //used for keeping track of what current color is


//loop through all values in income and outcome array (assumes they are same length). Fill the ranges array and create color zones. 
//Zones color up to a given point, therefore we need to push a color at the end, before it intersects
for (i = 0; i < income.length; i++) {
  ranges.push([i, income[i], outcome[i]]); //push to range array

  if (income[i] < outcome[i] && incomeBiggerBool) {
    incomeZones.push({
      value: intersect(i - 1, i, income[i - 1], income[i], outcome[i - 1], outcome[i]),
      fillColor: '#C0D890', // green
    }); //push to zone array 
    incomeBiggerBool = false;
  } else if (income[i] > outcome[i] && !incomeBiggerBool) {
    incomeZones.push({
      value: intersect(i - 1, i, income[i - 1], income[i], outcome[i - 1], outcome[i]),
      fillColor: '#ED4337' // red
    }); //push to zone array 
    incomeBiggerBool = true;
  }
}
//zones color up to a given point, therefore we need to push a color at the end as well:
if (incomeBiggerBool) {
  incomeZones.push({
    value: income.length,
    fillColor: '#C0D890' // green
  })
} else {
  incomeZones.push({
    value: income.length,
    fillColor: '#ED4337' // red
  })
}

var chart = Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'arearange'
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  exporting: {
    enabled: false
  },
  rangeSelector: {
    enabled: false
  },
  scrollbar: {
    enabled: false
  },
  navigator: {
    enabled: false
  },
  xAxis: {
    visible: false
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Example'
  },
  plotOptions: {},
  tooltip: {
    //Prettier tooltip:
    pointFormatter: function() {
      return 'Income: <b>' + this.low + '</b> -  Expenditures: <b>' + this.high + '</b>'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Income',
    data: ranges,
    zoneAxis: 'x',
    zones: incomeZones
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```